# How to flatten a column containing a list of dates as strings into just date?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe containing a column that has a list of dates stored as strings:

```
# sample dataframe
data = [[1, ["2019-08-02 08:30:56"]], [2, ["2020-08-02 08:30:56"]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["items", "dates"])
df["dates"] = df["dates"].astype(str)
df
```

```
  items                  dates
0   1   ['2019-08-02 08:30:56']
1   2   ['2020-08-02 08:30:56']
```

I would like to do several things:

- Convert from a list to a string.
- Convert the string to a date.
- Eliminate the time stamp.

So that the final dataset would look like this:

```
    items       dates
0   1      2019-08-02
1   2      2020-08-02
```

I am able to remove the list brackets by doing this:

```
df["dates_2"] = df["dates"].apply(lambda x: x[1:-1])
```

But I am wondering if there is a better way to do all of these things in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to apply `ast.literal_eval` to convert the column to `list`. Then `.explode()` it, convert to datetime and get a date part:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df["dates"] = df["dates"].apply(literal_eval)
df = df.explode("dates")
df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dates"]).dt.date

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   items       dates
0      1  2019-08-02
1      2  2020-08-02
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```py
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates.str.slice(1,-1)).dt.date
```

Output:

```
   items       dates
0      1  2019-08-02
1      2  2020-08-02
```

It's important to note that `dates` contains values of type str, each of which looks like a list when displayed but is not a list (each is a str) after running the following code as shown in the original question:

```py
# sample dataframe
data = [[1, ["2019-08-02 08:30:56"]], [2, ["2020-08-02 08:30:56"]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["items", "dates"])
df["dates"] = df["dates"].astype(str)
```

Therefore, all we need to do is:

- remove the `[` and `]` characters using `df.dates.str.slice(1,-1)` to get the substring of type str that looks like a datetime
- use `pd.to_datetime()` to convert the Series to Timestamps
- use [`.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) to get at the datetime-like properties of the values in the Series
- use the [`.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) accessor to convert to a numpy array of objects of type datetime.date

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = [[1, ["2019-08-02 08:30:56"]], [2, ["2020-08-02 08:30:56"]]]    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["items", "dates"]) 
df["dates"] = df["dates"].astype(str)
```

---

**Code**

```
pd.to_datetime(df['dates'].str[2:-2]).dt.normalize()
```

output

```
0   2019-08-02
1   2020-08-02
Name: dates, dtype: datetime64[ns] <-- chk dtype
```

if you want dtype is `object` not datetime, use following code:

```
df['dates'].str[2:12]

0    2019-08-02
1    2020-08-02
Name: dates, dtype: object <-- chk dtype
```